# Getting PolyglotException in karate API framework even though the request file exists on classpath

Tags: api, intellij-idea, karate

I am newbie in karate framework. I am trying to run my first karate test. However I am getting PolyglotException for request file even though the file exists on classpath. The error is "org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: not found: requests/first.json". The error goes away if I place request file in the features folder.
The script I have written is

```
Feature: Demoing scenario outline

  Background:
    * url 'https://reqres.in'
    * def endpoint = '/api/users'

  @TestId-43343
  Scenario Outline: first test with scenario outline
    * def name1 = <name>
    * def job1 = <job>
    * def requestBody = read('classpath:requests/first.json')
    Given path endpoint
    And request requestBody
    And print requestBody
    When method POST
    Then status 201
    And print response
    And match $.job == <job>
    And match $.name == <name>
    Examples:
      | name     | job      |
      | 'abc'    | 'DEV'    |
      | 'hjl'    | 'DEVOPS' |
```

features and requests folders are present under java.
Your help is appreciated.

Comment: for these kinds of issues, please follow this process: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue, else no one can help

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#classpath) in the documentation, the default directory when you use classpath depends on how you have configured maven testResource. Try using the full path like

`* def requestBody = read('classpath:src/test/java/requests/first.json')`

Comment: Not working. I had already tried it

Comment: Please check the snippet from pom.xml
 <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>